# Azure spring app deployment, controller 404 not found

Tags: java, azure, gradle, http-status-code-404

I am trying to deploy spring app on Azure App Service. I added to build.gradle instructions with plugin like below:

```
azurewebapp {
    subscription = 'xxx'
    resourceGroup = 'xxx'
    appName = 'xxx'
    region = 'westus'
    runtime {
        os = 'Linux'
        webContainer = 'Tomcat 10.0'
        javaVersion = 'Java 17'
    }
    appSettings {
        DatabaseConnectionString = "xxx"
        DatabaseUsername = "xxxx"
        DatabasePassword = "xxxx"
    }
    auth {
    }
```

Then after command gradle azureWebAppDeply I got information about success, but when I tried to reach any endpoint I got 404, even when the app is just 1 controller with a String return type like  below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("any")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class Example {

    @GetMapping
    public String re() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with what to do, to be able to reach endpoints?

Comment: How are you deploying your application(any IDE/CLI)?

Comment: I am using InteliJJ, but in order to deploy i use command 
''''
gradle azureWebAppDeploy
''''

Comment: Can you provide your application link, if it is available in GitHub(if it doesn't have any sensitive information).

Comment: Well my app is in a private repository but I had the same issue, well I created a new spring project with an older spring version to check it without database 
https://github.com/Coriv/Azure
there is just 1 controller class which return string and some settings in build.gradle file.

its deployed here 
https://team-management.azurewebsites.net

with deployment status success, but when i am trying to reach 

https://team-management.azurewebsites.net/any there is 404

Comment: I will check and update.

Comment: I tried deploying via intellij and it worked. @Coriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to reach any endpoint I got 404

This could be because the application is not deployed properly. Check if all the files of your application is available in the Azure App Service.

I have deployed your application using IntelliJ IDE and could see the expected results after running the deployed application.

**Steps to follow:**

- `Right click on the project=> Select Azure=> Choose Deploy to Azure Web Apps`:

[image]

- Select your `web app` to deploy spring boot app as shown below and fill the remaining details accordingly:

[image]

**Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

- Make sure ***your application is deployed properly*** and you can see all the ***project files*** in ***KUDU*** site(`https://<web_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`).
- `Azure App Service=>Advanced Tools=>Go=>`KUDU site will be opened.
- Go to `File Manager=>site/wwwroot/`, check if all the project files are deployed.

[image]
[image]

**Response:**
Browse the application site `https://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/any`:

[image]